# Alternative to member variables in C

Tags: c, member

I have a file with several related functions which need to share a piece of data.  While I would like to avoid the use of a global variable,  The best solution I can think of is to declare a static in the file, but I'd like to restrict the scope to the file.  I think that can be done with a `static` declaration.  Are there other, superior alternatives?

In an object oriented environment, they would all be members of a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, declaring a global static variable pretty much covers what you need to do (provided that the variable needs to change; otherwise, use a macro). You can declare a static variable at the global level and have it be private to the file.

Also, be aware that this is totally not threadsafe.

Answer (score 4):

While a static would work, I think what you really want is a struct.  Each function would take this struct as a param.  So something like:

```
typedef struct mystruct_s {
    ...
} mystruct_t;

void myfunc1(mystruct_t *mystruct);
void myfunc2(mystruct_t *mystruct);
```

One advantage to this approach is that its thread-safe.  ie, you could have multiple instances of mystruct running at the same time.  Its also cleaner than having what's essentially a global variable (even if it is restricted in scope to one file).

Comment: That's a cool idea.  It looks like it would require the callers to these functions to have a copy of the pointer, which I suppose could be supplied by a call to `mystruct_s* get_mystruct_ptr(){return &mystruct_t}` or is there a way for the callers to not need it?

Comment: The callers would need the pointer.  They would create the structure on the stack, or they could call some kind of `create_mystruct()` to malloc it (note that you would need a corresponding `destroy_mystruct()`).

Answer (score 2):

A `static` will restrict the scope to the file, but there will only be one of then.  That means you can only ever have one user of that set of functions if there's any state involved.

It's better to have a handle with a lifecycle that you can have scoped however you need it.  To wit:

```
Foo * handle = foo_create();  // Allocates and initializes a structure

foo_operation1(handle);
foo_operation2(handle);

foo_destroy(handle);          // Deallocates the structure
```

This guarantees that only code that knows about `handle` will be able to do anything that alters it.

Answer (score 1):

`static` would limit the scope to the current compile (the file). But it is a global declaration. The alternative is to pass the object around from function to function as a parameter. It's pretty common.